# Measure the time it takes for queries to run in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a simple nodejs program to test queries performance but I have this issue where I have an array of queries and when I loop over them and measure their timings, the second one is always faster than the first one, like let's say I have queries A and B, if the array looks like this
[A, B], B is gonna be faster, but if I changed the order to [B, A], A is gonna be faster, but running them individually ( like having a list of just A or B ) or in psql I found that they both almost have identical results.
Here is the code.

index.js

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');
const queryPref = require('./src/QueryPref');

require('dotenv').config();

(async ()=> await queryPref())();
```

queryPref.js

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');


const queries = [
  {
    'queryStr': 'SELECT * FROM tabluno where user_name = $1',
    'options': ['08544f75d007ae439925bb21fe48c64c'],
  },
  {
    'queryStr': 'SELECT * FROM tabluno2 where user_name = $1',
    'options': ['f67a10e60fde706bb6c5948374b385e5'],
  },
]

function initClient() {
  console.log('opening a new connection');
  const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'indexing-is-really-hard',
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: 5432 // default port for postgres
  });

  return client;
}

async function queryPref() {
  for(const query of queries) {
    let pool = new Client({
      user: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'indexing-is-really-hard',
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      port: 5432, // default port for postgres
    });

    await pool.connect();
    await pool.query('SELECT 1');

    let avg = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)    {
      const start = performance.now();
      await pool.query(query.queryStr, query.options)
      const end = performance.now();
      avg += end - start;
    }
    avg /= 1000;

    console.log(`${query.queryStr} took an avg of ${avg.toFixed(3)}ms`)

    pool.end();
    pool = null;
  }
}


module.exports = queryPref;
```

as you can see I'm trying to init a new client for each query, but it seems like it's doing nothing.

I've tried using connection Pool instead of a client, yet got the same results ( second one being always faster ).
I've also tried measuring the average over 1000 queries with client and pool, but gave the same result again.

Edit:
[results from nodejs app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91f20.png)

[results from psql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6drlX.png)

Comment: Sounds like the lib you're using defers the actual connection until it needs it. (I think most do.) So add a throwaway at the beginning that hits the DB but doesn't get recorded, to make sure there's a connection before you test what you're really interested in. (Also beware of simplistic performance tests. Real-world data is generally more useful. PostgresSQL has statistics collectors you can access.)

Comment: I've tried to add `await client.query('SELECT 1');` under the connection once, and in the queries array another time, it made the first one faster ( it's obvious ), but the second one was even faster again. I always thought that the second one was faster because I'm in the same client, and running more and more queries in the same client makes them faster for some reason, so my first solution was generating a new client for each query and then measure the query timing, I've tried to end the connection at the end of the query and make the client = null, but also didn't work.

Comment: How much faster? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I've added an image of the results in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for loop, you can calculate it like this :

```
const startTime =  Date.now();
const timeTaken = Date.now() - startTime;
```

and add the time Taken in the common variable outside of your for loop.

Comment: I've updated the code in the queryPref function in the question you can check it and see if that is what you wanted to do.